# service problem

Tags: ros, rosservice, service, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I defined a server called DetectsObs.srv

```
float32 x
float32 y
float32 theta
float32 threshold
---
Points obstacles
bool obs
bool processFinished
```

and two msg type
Point.msg

```
float32 x
float32 y
```

and Points.msg

```
Point[] points
```

I have a service whose response is `obstacle_detection::DetectsObs::Response &res` (obstacle_detection is my package) I want to set the field obstacles of my response but if I do

```
obstacle_detection::Point obstacle;
obstacle.x = 0;
obstacle.y = 0;
res.obstacles[0] = obstacle;
```

I get this error

error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘res->obstacle_detection::DetectsObsResponse_std::allocator<void >::obstacles[0]’

What should i do to fix it.
Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59746/service-problem/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The way you have defined it, `obstacles` is a `Points` msg, not a vector of `Point`s, and thus has only one member: `points`.  You would access it with `res.obstacles.points[0]`.  Since `points` is a vector, make sure you `resize` it first or `push_back` the element instead.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1